# Are controller instance variables accessible in the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Given a file posts.js.coffee.erb in the asset pipeline, I can do this

```
  alert "<%= Rails.env %>"
```

but what about accessing instance variables defined in the controller?

```
  alert "<%= @posts.to_json %>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. I was trying to add theming functionality to a blog application, and it turns out that it won't see the application helper methods or instance variables.

What I have done instead is create css view for the show action in themes, something like **show.css.erb**, which will be accessed via url like **/themes/black.css**

The same can be done with javascript, so if you need a specific javascript view just create a view for **posts.js.erb**

This technique is not even new in rails. I remember someone asking in twitter if you could do something like that in asp.net mvc back in 09

Additionally you will need to have your controller respond to that format, the following is a snippet from the app I was working on.

```
def show
  @theme = Theme.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.css
  end
end
```

Comment: Just clarifying what's going on in my original question: you can access Rails.env in the asset pipeline at startup when the assets are being packaged. But once that's done, the assets are served as static files while the app is running. Nothing can be interpolated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to alert this from the view, not a static js file.